# For each variable not available within for each scope

Tags: vb.net, foreach

The backstory is that I want to be able to initialize a blank row on for a DataTable without having to always check for `DBNull.Value`.  I have an extension method that creates a new blank row and then fills each of the values in the row with the default type for that column.

```vb
<Extension()> _
Public Function NewBlankRow(ByVal table As DataTable) As DataRow
    Dim row As DataRow = table.NewRow()
    For Each col As DataColumn In table.Columns
        row(col.ColumnName) = CType(Nothing, col.DataType)
    Next
    Return row
End Function
```

I get the following message for the second usage of col (the one within `CType`)

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'col'
```

For C-Sharper's, Calling `CType(Nothing, T)` should be the same as calling `Default<T>`

Is there a better way to do this?  Why can't I access col within `CType`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CType` is not a runtime function.  It's compile time.  The data type in the second argument must be a specified at compile time.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x2877xb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

> CType is compiled inline, which means that the conversion code is part of the code that evaluates the expression. In some cases there is no call to a procedure to accomplish the conversion, which makes execution faster.

It's not the same as `Default<T>` in this instance because `NewBlankRow` is not a generic method.  Regardless, `Default<T>` is also compile time and is not available when `T` is specified as a run-time expression.

To create a default instance of `col.DataType` you could use reflection, such as `Activator.CreateInsatnce(col.DataType)`.